# CUDA kernel to compare matrix entries, weighted with a pattern

Tags: performance, c, matrix, cuda, kernel

I wonder if it's possible to optimize this code in CUDA. Could I get any hints how to? Equivalent algorithm runs faster in Matlab for me, but there I'm doing matrix operations.

## Compution

I'm not asking how to change computation or optimize math operations. But nonetheless I will describe goal of this kernel.

Basically I need to do \$1e5\$ of `for` loops. Each of these `for` loops is computing weight matrix `W += Wi` where `Wi` is weight of pattern `Pi`. There are, for example, 400 patterns `P`. After getting `W` we pick random index `k` of some pattern from `P`, then compute `S = W*P[k]` and check hamming distance between feed `P[k]` and `S`.

I implemented all this algorithm in single kernel. All patterns are generated before hand (here as dummy 1). Each pattern is supposed to be different so together there are \$1e5 \cdot 400\$ patterns.

Each pattern is of size `N = 100`. Total memory of patterns is:

\$1e5 \cdot 400 \cdot 100 \cdot sizeof(int) = 15.3GB\$.

I have only 6GB of GPU memory so I had put this patterns to chunks.

## Kernel structure

My kernel is organized like that:

- each block computes for one time step for no of steps: \$1e5\$/`nChunks`
- each thread computes weights for one pattern from nP patterns
- some lucky thread is picked randomly and:

  - computes state of network after feeding some pattern
  - then computes error between feed and state

## What are ways to optimize this kernel?

My ideas:

- Should I replace for loops inside kernel with some high performance functions?
- Make simpler kernel and run it in async with \$1e5\$ calls?

I'm asking for this to better understand how to use CUDA properly in some algorithm rather than in some general cases like mat mul, etc.

### Kernel

#define N_N 100

```
__global__ void mykernel(cuint nSteps, cuint nP, cuint nN, cuint caseIdx, const int *P, float *errorB) {


    cuint stepIdx = blockIdx.x;
    cuint stepSize = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    cuint patternIdx = threadIdx.x;


    if (patternIdx < nP && stepIdx < nSteps) {

        __shared__ volatile float s_W[N_N * N_N]; //weights updated from all patterns
        //extern __shared__ volatile int s_P[]; //each thread has his own pattern
        __shared__ volatile int s_F[N_N];  //we share same feed pattern
        __shared__ volatile float s_S[N_N];


        float Wij = 0;
        float _N = 1.f / nN;

        cuint idx = stepSize + patternIdx * nN;

        //compute W matrix from weights of all patterns
        #pragma unroll
        for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
            #pragma unroll
            for (int j = 0; j < nN; ++j) {
                s_W[i * nN + j] += P[idx + i] * P[idx + j] * _N;
            }
        }

        int feedIdx = 0; //random index from range [0, nP)
        if (patternIdx == feedIdx) {
            #pragma unroll
            for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
                s_F[i] = P[idx + i];
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
        //compute state for given feed index, only once
        if (patternIdx == 0) {
            float Si;
            #pragma unroll
            for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
                Si = 0;
                #pragma unroll
                for (int j = 0; j < nN; ++j) {
                    Si += s_W[i * nN + j] * s_F[i];
                }
                s_S[i] = Si;
            }
            #pragma unroll
            for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
                errorB[caseIdx] += s_S[i] != s_F[i];
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Complete code:

```
# To run this code with profiling do:
# nvprof ./hello --system-profiling on --print-gpu-trace on --profile-from-start off


//#include "cuda_reduce_benchmark.cuh"
//#include "hopfield_deterministic.cuh"

#ifdef USE_CUDA_DUMMY

#include "cuda_dummy.h"
//#include "std_utils.h"

#else
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>

#ifdef USE_CUBLAS
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#endif

#ifdef USE_CURAND
#include <curand.h>
#endif

// Utilities and system includes
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <helper_functions.h>

#define __CUDA_INTERNAL_COMPILATION__

#include <math_functions.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

#undef __CUDA_INTERNAL_COMPILATION__
#endif


#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>


#define BTOMB(x) (x)/1024/1024
#define MBTOB(x) (x)*1024*1024

#ifdef USE_CUDA_DUMMY
#define cuint const unsigned int
#define uint unsigned int
#else
typedef const unsigned int cuint;
typedef unsigned int uint;
#endif

#define fori(s, n) for(int i=s; i<n; ++i)
#define forj(s, n) for(int j=s; j<n; ++j)
#define fork(s, n) for(int k=s; k<n; ++k)
#define forl(s, n) for(int l=s; l<n; ++l)
#define forh(s, n) for(int h=s; h<n; ++h)
#define forauto(vec) for(auto & i : vec)

template<typename T>
T nextpow2(T x) {
    T n = x;
    --n;

    n |= n >> 1;
    n |= n >> 2;
    n |= n >> 4;
    n |= n >> 8;
    n |= n >> 16;

    return n + 1;
}


#define CUDA_ECHO_ERROR(e, strs) { \
    char a[255];                                                    \
    if (e != cudaSuccess) {                                         \
        strncpy(a, strs, 255);                                      \
        fprintf(stderr,                                                     \
        "CUDA Failed to run %s at file %s line %d :: errorCode : %s\n",     \
        a, __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(e) );                     \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                 \
    }                                                                       \
}

#define CUDA_KERNEL_DYN(kernel, bpg, tpb, shd, ...){                     \
    kernel<<<bpg,tpb,shd>>>( __VA_ARGS__ );                     \
    cudaError_t err= cudaGetLastError();                   \
    CUDA_ECHO_ERROR(err, #kernel);                                 \
}

#define CUDA_KERNEL(kernel, bpg, tpb, ...){                     \
    kernel<<<bpg,tpb>>>( __VA_ARGS__ );                     \
    cudaError_t err= cudaGetLastError();                   \
    CUDA_ECHO_ERROR(err, #kernel);                              \
    }


#define CUDA_MEMSET(darr, v, T, n){                                                               \
       cudaError_t err = cudaMemset(darr, v, n * sizeof(T));                             \
        CUDA_ECHO_ERROR( err, "cudaMemset in " #darr );                                        \
    }

#define CUDA_FREEDEV(darr){                     \
       cudaError_t err = cudaFree(darr );               \
        CUDA_ECHO_ERROR( err, "cudaFree the " #darr );   \
}

#define CUDA_FREEHST(harr){                     \
       cudaError_t err = cudaFreeHost(harr );               \
        CUDA_ECHO_ERROR( err, "cudaFreeHost the " #harr );   \
}



#define CUDA_MALDEV(darr, T, n){                                                   \
       cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc( ( void** ) &darr, n* sizeof( T ) );                 \
        CUDA_ECHO_ERROR( err, "cudaMalloc the " #darr );                                          \
    }

#define CUDA_MALHST(harr, T, n){                                                               \
       cudaError_t err = cudaMallocHost( ( void** ) &harr, n* sizeof( T ) );                                 \
        CUDA_ECHO_ERROR( err, "cudaMallocHost the " #harr );                                                      \
    }


#define CUDA_CP2HST(darr, harr, T, n){                                                               \
       cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpy(harr, darr, n*sizeof( T ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);                             \
        CUDA_ECHO_ERROR( err, "cudaMemcpy from " #darr " to " #harr );                                        \
    }

inline void cuda_get_device_prop(cudaDeviceProp &prop, int device) {
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, device);
    printf("...Device Number: %d\n", device);
    printf("   Device name: %s\n", prop.name);
    printf("   Memory Clock Rate (KHz): %d\n",
           prop.memoryClockRate);
    printf("   Memory Bus Width (bits): %d\n",
           prop.memoryBusWidth);
    printf("   Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): %f\n\n",
           2.0 * prop.memoryClockRate * (prop.memoryBusWidth / 8) / 1.0e6);
}

inline cuint cuda_count_devices() {
    int nDevices;

    cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);

    printf("CUDA nDevices : %d\n", nDevices);

    return (cuint) (nDevices);
}

inline cuint init_cuda_gpu(cuint device) {
    // Init GPU Device

    cuint nGpu = cuda_count_devices();

    if (!nGpu) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUDA no devices ERROR, cant init device : %d\n", device);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("CUDA init device : %d\n", device);

    CUdevice dev;
    CUcontext context;
    cuInit(device);
    cuDeviceGet(&dev, device);
    cuCtxCreate(&context, device, dev);
    cudaError_t err = cudaSetDevice(device);
    CUDA_ECHO_ERROR(err, "init_cuda_gpu");


    return nGpu;

}

/*
EACH BLOCK IN GRID: contains one time step to compute error by
 W = P * P
 F = P[randIdx]
 S = W * F
 error = S != F
 EACH THREAD IN BLOCK: handles one pattern to compute weights Wp
 this weights are summed up for all patterns to one W matrix
 W += Wp



*/



#define N_N 100

__global__ void mykernel(cuint nSteps, cuint nP, cuint nN, cuint caseIdx, const int *P, float *errorB) {


    cuint stepIdx = blockIdx.x;
    cuint stepSize = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    cuint patternIdx = threadIdx.x;


    if (patternIdx < nP && stepIdx < nSteps) {

        __shared__ volatile float s_W[N_N * N_N]; //weights updated from all patterns
        //extern __shared__ volatile int s_P[]; //each thread has his own pattern
        __shared__ volatile int s_F[N_N];  //we share same feed pattern
        __shared__ volatile float s_S[N_N];


        float Wij = 0;
        float _N = 1.f / nN;

        cuint idx = stepSize + patternIdx * nN;

        //compute W matrix from weights of all patterns
        #pragma unroll
        for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
            #pragma unroll
            for (int j = 0; j < nN; ++j) {
                s_W[i * nN + j] += P[idx + i] * P[idx + j] * _N;
            }
        }

        int feedIdx = 0; //random index from range [0, nP)
        if (patternIdx == feedIdx) {
            #pragma unroll
            for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
                s_F[i] = P[idx + i];
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
        //compute state for given feed index, only once
        if (patternIdx == 0) {
            float Si;
            #pragma unroll
            for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
                Si = 0;
                #pragma unroll
                for (int j = 0; j < nN; ++j) {
                    Si += s_W[i * nN + j] * s_F[i];
                }
                s_S[i] = Si;
            }
            #pragma unroll
            for (int i = 0; i < nN; ++i) {
                errorB[caseIdx] += s_S[i] != s_F[i];
            }

        }

    }
}

#define thr thrust

int main() {
    #ifdef USE_CUDA_DUMMY
    cudaError_t err;
    #endif

    uint deviceIdx = 0;
    cudaDeviceProp prop;

    cuint nGpu = init_cuda_gpu(deviceIdx);

    cudaProfilerStart();

    cuda_get_device_prop(prop, deviceIdx);


    int nN = N_N;
    int nP = 400;

    size_t maxGlobMem = BTOMB(prop.totalGlobalMem);
    size_t maxGlobMem_1p6 = nextpow2<size_t>(maxGlobMem * 1 / 6);
    size_t maxGlobMem_2p6 = 2 * maxGlobMem_1p6;
    size_t maxGlobMem_3p6 = 3 * maxGlobMem_1p6;
    size_t maxGlobMem_4p6 = 4 * maxGlobMem_1p6;
    size_t maxGlobMem_5p6 = 5 * maxGlobMem_1p6;

    uint maxThrPerBlc = (uint) prop.maxThreadsPerBlock;
    uint maxShm = (uint) prop.sharedMemPerBlock;
    int maxGridx = prop.maxGridSize[0];

    printf("globMem: %zu maxThrPerBlc: %d, shm: %d, gridsize: %d\n",
           maxGlobMem, maxThrPerBlc, maxShm, maxGridx);

    size_t maxGlobFloat = maxGlobMem / sizeof(float);
    size_t maxGlobFloat_4p6 = maxGlobMem_4p6 / sizeof(float);
    size_t maxGlobFloat_3p6 = maxGlobMem_3p6 / sizeof(float);
    size_t maxGlobFloat_2p6 = maxGlobMem_2p6 / sizeof(float);
    size_t maxGlobFloat_1p6 = maxGlobMem_1p6 / sizeof(float);
    size_t maxGlobInt_1p6 = maxGlobMem_1p6 / sizeof(int);

    printf("maxGlobFloat_4p6: %zu, maxGlobFloat_3p6: %zu,   maxGlobFloat_2p6: %zu,  maxGlobFloat_1p6: %zu, maxGrid: %d\n",
           maxGlobFloat_4p6, maxGlobFloat_3p6, maxGlobFloat_2p6, maxGlobFloat_1p6, maxGridx);

    size_t nSteps = (size_t) 1e5;

    size_t nPatternsPerTime = nSteps * nN;

    size_t nTotPatterns = nP * nPatternsPerTime;

    size_t nChunksP = BTOMB(nTotPatterns) / (size_t) (maxGlobFloat) + 1;
    size_t nChunksP_4p6 = BTOMB(nTotPatterns) / (size_t) (maxGlobFloat_4p6) + 1;
    size_t nChunksP_3p6 = BTOMB(nTotPatterns) / (size_t) (maxGlobFloat_3p6) + 1;
    size_t nChunksP_2p6 = BTOMB(nTotPatterns) / (size_t) (maxGlobFloat_2p6) + 1;
    size_t nChunksP_1p6 = BTOMB(nTotPatterns) / (size_t) (maxGlobFloat_1p6) + 1;

    printf("np2(1e5): %zu, nChunksP: %zu/%zu = %zu\n", nP * nSteps, BTOMB(nTotPatterns), maxGlobFloat, nChunksP);
    printf("np2(1e5): %zu, nChunksP_4p6: %zu/%zu = %zu\n", nP * nSteps, BTOMB(nTotPatterns), maxGlobFloat_4p6, nChunksP_4p6);
    printf("np2(1e5): %zu, nChunksP_3p6: %zu/%zu = %zu\n", nP * nSteps, BTOMB(nTotPatterns), maxGlobFloat_3p6, nChunksP_3p6);
    printf("np2(1e5): %zu, nChunksP_2p6: %zu/%zu = %zu\n", nP * nSteps, BTOMB(nTotPatterns), maxGlobFloat_2p6, nChunksP_2p6);
    printf("np2(1e5): %zu, nChunksP_1p6: %zu/%zu = %zu\n", nP * nSteps, BTOMB(nTotPatterns), maxGlobFloat_1p6, nChunksP_1p6);

    size_t nStepsChunk = nSteps / nChunksP_4p6;
    size_t sChunk = nStepsChunk * nP * nN;

    printf("nStepsChunk: %zu, sizePatSteps=%zu\n", nStepsChunk, sChunk);


    float *dev_ErrorB;
    float *hst_ErrorB;
    int *dev_P;

    CUDA_MALHST(hst_ErrorB, float, 100);
    CUDA_MALDEV(dev_ErrorB, float, 100);
    CUDA_MALDEV(dev_P, int, sChunk);

    dim3 blcPerGrd(nStepsChunk);
    dim3 thrPerBlc(nP);

    printf("sizeof(int)=%zu, sizeof(float)=%zu\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(float));

    printf("CALL KERNEL: blckPerGrd: %zu, thrPerBlc: %d, SHM: %zu/%zu\n",
           nSteps, maxThrPerBlc, maxShm / sizeof(int), maxShm / sizeof(float));

    fori(0,nChunksP_4p6){
        CUDA_KERNEL(mykernel,
                    blcPerGrd, thrPerBlc,
                    nStepsChunk, nP, nN, 0, dev_P, dev_ErrorB);
    }

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    CUDA_CP2HST(dev_ErrorB, hst_ErrorB, float, 100);

    cudaProfilerStop();


    CUDA_FREEDEV(dev_P);
    CUDA_FREEDEV(dev_ErrorB);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: actually it seems that kernel dont work properly, will have time for it after exams in august, so until this time put this question on hiatus